# WooCommerce Add to Cart custom redirection for specific product IDs

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to hook in on the Add to cart redirect, changing the URL for specific product-ID
As a starting point, I found the following code (Source: https://jeroensormani.com/redirect-users-after-add-to-cart/)

```
   function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
    
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || ! is_numeric( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
        return $url;
    }
    
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) );
    
    // Only redirect the product IDs in the array to the checkout
    if ( in_array( $product_id, array( 1, 16, 24) ) ) {
            $url = "https://mywebsite.com/";
        }
        
        return $url;
    
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

Which seems approved by others. For me, it seems to ignore the redirect infusion when a condition is applied to it. It works when the condition is left out:

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
    $url = "https://mywebsite.com/";
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

My conclusion/guess is, that there is something in the condition or the filter, that is outdated, but I cannot figure out what's wrong. I have researching other simuler code, based on the woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect hook, and tried countless snippets, and combinations of functions, but I cannot get any of them working, whenever a condition is applied to it.

[Edit] Now that I think about it, It could very well be a query problem. But not too sure how to go about that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First There are 2 available arguments for `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` filter hook. So yes the code you found is a bit outdated.

For everyone, this hook works if you have enabled ***"Redirect to the cart page after successful addition"*** option on WooCommerce Settings > Products *(tab)*.

Now, there are 2 kinds of add to cart in WooCommerce:

- **Ajax** add to cart,
- and **Normal** add to cart.

The hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` only works for **Normal** add to cart to target specific products, as you cant handle the product ID with **Ajax** add to cart for the redirection *(see below)*.

For **Ajax add to cart** [the hook is defined in here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php#L559) like:

```
'cart_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', wc_get_cart_url(), null ),
```

where the 2nd argument is set to `null`.

---

For **Normal Add to cart** [the hook is defined in here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L799) like:

```
$url = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', $url, $adding_to_cart );
```

where `$adding_to_cart` *(2nd argument)* is the product object [defined in here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L779) like:

```
$adding_to_cart = wc_get_product( $product_id );
```

---

Here is a correct example of working code for **Normal Add to cart** handling specific product Ids custom redirection:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $redirect_url, $product ) {
    $product_ids = array( 37, 22, 53, 40 ); // Here set your product Ids in the array

    // Only redirect the product IDs in the array to the checkout
    if ( is_object($product) && in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids ) ) {
        $redirect_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works for normal add to cart.

> To handle **Ajax add to cart redirection** to a custom Url **for specific products**, Some jQuery code will be required…

Comment: Beautiful ansvar and explanation. I should included the info about my wc settings. It was for "normal add to cart redirect ,with Ajax disabled."

Your code threw a fatal error in the Cart, but after some testing I have found it to be a conflict with a plugin. Once plugin was disabled, the code worked.

I will do some testing and try to figure out what it was. Will return if I found the solution, or with some info on the error.

Again, thank you very much, you are a great help!

Comment: Welcome! The hook work for both, but doesn't handle product detection for Ajax add to cart.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, been trying a lot to figure this error out.
After adding the working snippet suggested by LoicTheAztec,
I get this error, when loading the "Cart" page, regardless of it being empty or not.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function pza_custom_add_to_cart_redirect(), 1 passed in
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287
> and exactly 3 expected in
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php:
> 149 Stack trace: #0
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287):
> pza_custom_add_to_cart_redirect('https://*DOMAIN*...') #1
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(212):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters('https://*DOMAIN*...', Array) #2
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/uni-woo-custom-product-options-premium/includes/class-uni-cpo-frontend-scripts.php(959):
> apply_filters('woocommerce_add...', 'https://*DOMAIN*...') #3
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287):
> Uni_Cpo_Frontend_Scripts::load_scripts('') #4
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /home/*DOMAIN*/public_ in
> /home/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php
> on line 149

It seems to be a conflict with the UNI-CPO Plugin. When disabling the plugin, the issue is gone. I am having a hard time figurering out, if it is the fault of the snippet or the plugin, and how to get around it, if at all possible.

Comment: The problem is in your child theme's functions.php, on line 149. For the `pza_custom_add_to_cart_redirect` function you are passing only one argument but the hook expects 3. You need to define them. Look for the hook in the plugin documentation. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) you will find more information.

Comment: Ok, been giving it a few days, trying to unwrap this issue. The issue is, as you can see above, in LoicTheAztec's solution. We are asking for, and passing 2 arguments, which are returned to the filter. Also, this code is working. It only gives this odd error when a third-party plugin is enabled(Uni Cpo). The plugin has nothing to do with the function, yet it seems to put a stick in the wheel between Woocommmerce and this hook function.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the Uni CPO plugin. They are hijacking the add to cart redirect in some odd way. I tested by commenting out there redirect code, and the snippet worked again, but not for CPO products. I ended up taking a different approach, and just made somme conditions for wp-redirect to redirect from cart, if product was presented. Skipping the whole add to cart hook.